# nginx error_page forward instead of redirect

Tags: nginx, single-page-application

I have an nginx as a reverse proxy, which does some `proxy_pass` things. The Proxy is in front of an angular SPA with HTML5 routing enabled + other ugly stuff around so I can't handle the 404 on the Server which deliveres the Page.

At the moment I have the following config:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;

    server {
        listen  3000;
        location /int {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9131/int;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "127.0.0.1";
        }
        location /app/static {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9131/int/static;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "127.0.0.1";
        }
        location /app/api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9131/int/api;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "127.0.0.1";
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_pass https://example.com/;
            sub_filter 'https://example.com/int' 'http://$host:$server_port/int';
            sub_filter '<base />' '<base href="/app/" />';  
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            error_page 404 = @fallback;
        }

        # EDIT: after comment, but got the following Error: 
        #   "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular
        #   expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, 
        #   or inside "limit_except" block in ...\nginx-1.14.2/conf
        #   /nginx.conf:37
        location @fallback {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/app;
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to `example.com/app/foobar` I got a redirect to `example.com/app`. What I want is a forward, so that I got the content of `example.com/app` without modifying the URL or the Statuscode. Then the SPA could handle the routing.

## Edit:

Added config with named location (`@fallback`}

Comment: The [`error_page` manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) gives a few options. The named `location` looks like it might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I've allready found that one, but then I got the following Errormessage: "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in ...\nginx-1.14.2/conf/nginx.conf:37

Comment: If you want to rewrite the URI, use a `rewrite...break` - try removing the `/app` part from the `proxy_pass` statement and adding `rewrite ^(.*)$ /app$1 break;`